# How do I implement a userspace implementation of the character device for EtherCAT master?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, driver, ethercat

I am working on a personal project and want to try to come up with an implementation of the character device in the userspace instead of the kernelspace. I am using this github project https://github.com/ningfei/ethercat. I know it is something which is really exhaustive as I would need to replace all the linux kernel system calls by a mock representation. Can someone give me an idea on how to do so?

The image below shows the ethercat architecture.[Ethercat architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSTv3.png)

Answer (score 0):

So with other words you want all parts of EtherLAB master run in userspace,
then try http://fh-soft.de/src/ethercat-userspace.html .

Bear in mind that a pure userspace version of EtherLAB master means higher latency and lower cycle frequency.